# How to select number of matching strings in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Im creating an browser game where there is a database of players. Team power is counted by many factors, one of them is nationality of the player.

ExampleTeam:
Polish
American
American
Sweden
Sweden

I need a query which will return something like array or table including numbers 1, 2, 2. Is it even possible?

Comment: What does those numbers represent even?

Comment: Indeed, what are you trying to count exactly?

Comment: These numbers represent count of matching nationalities. In ExampleTeam there is one Polish, two Americans and two Swedens. The whole system of nationalities should work like no match: +0, two players from the same country: +10 etc. Thats why I need that. Sorry for not being precise.

Comment: So what's the exact result of the example you gave?

Comment: So the exact result is 1, 2, 2. I need some function which will return just number 5, if all of the players in A team have the same nationality, 1, 4 if there are 4 the same and 1 other, or even 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 if all of the players have different nationalities. I really don't know how to explain it, but i hope you understand.

Comment: @Naratov your examples are confusing. What 'number' do you expect to return in your example 1,2,2,  or when the team is a 2,3? What bonus attaches to 2,3 , is it the same as 4,1?  How does any number you return relate to a bonus? Must a team have 5 members, what happens when the number a team has fewer, or more than, 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change the table names and column names to match your problem.

```
SELECT nationality, COUNT(nationality) as num
FROM Teams 
GROUP BY nationality;
```

This returns:

```
+-------------------------+
| nationality |    num    |
+-------------------------+
|    Polish   |     1     |
|   American  |     2     |
|    Sweden   |     2     |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please select it as the chosen answer

Comment: My table is called 'players'. Every player has an id, nationality, skill. Next table - teams has id's of players playing in this specific team. What i want to get is numbers like above from any team i select.

Comment: Use edit on your question and put the schema details where they might help others answer it.

Comment: I think this is an acceptable answer to your problem. SO is not a place to get others to do the work for you. You can look up how to join tables and use this code to do what you want.